# Bloomberg Python Question - How do you access PRTU via python?

Tags: bloomberg, python

I am having some trouble using python to access Bloomberg as I cant find much documentation. All I really need to do is a simple lookup of dates in the PRTU function of Bloomberg, PRTU  via a python program.

Can anyone help me out with this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I am also trying to access `PRTU` but I do not see how neither with excel add_in or python. Can you please update this question if you happened to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your best bet would be to get setup with an `SFTP` account with Bloomberg.

Just contact your rep to get the ball rolling.  We upload 10's of protfolio's 10's of times a day.

I don't think there is an actual api for pulling data from `PRTU` as I'm not sure exaclty what you'd pull other than the last upload time.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to pull. We've had some issues with data not getting uploaded/downloaded and I'm just trying to automate these small things. Ill try contacting my rep again. Thanks chollida!